# Clone native android alarm screen with react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

The android alarm screen turns on at the scheduled alarm time.
I want to use a push notification to trigger a similar screen (even when the screen is turned off and is locked and the app does not run) using a react-native app. It should play a sound and have a button to stop the sound.

Does anyone know how to do it? If you just know how to do it with nativescript or similar javascript-based frameworks, this would also be helpful.

Using plain notifications, the phone vibrates and plays a short sound. However, this is not good enough, because it is not disturbing as an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

React Native is not mature enough to spawn a screen automatically, but you can implement it yourself if you have Java skills.